# how to pass {% csrf_token %} in javascript which is returning a html form

Tags: javascript, django

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value){
    return '<form id="addtextbox" name="addtextbox" method="post">'+
        '<div class="col-xs-4">'+
        '<label for="ex3">Enter Alertname</label>'+
        '<input class="form-control" id="userInput" type="text" name="alertname1" placeholder="Enter the alerts..">'+
        '<br>'+
'<i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden=
"true"></i>'+
'       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">'+

      '</div>'+
        '</form>'
}
```

It is throwing an error csrf token missing but even I include ''+'{% csrf_token %}' it is throwning an error.Please guide me in this

Comment: Save it in a global variable and use it across all other files. try `<script>window.CSRF_TOKEN = "{% csrf_token %}"</script>`

Comment: @Rajesh can you bit explain how to use in the js script.Like Shall i have window.CSRF_token in  a variable and just pass in the form.Can you please explain a bit>I am new to this field completly

Comment: Once you do above step, you can access this variable as `window.CSRF_TOKEN` anywhere.

Comment: @Rajesh It worked :) thanks